# Passing input from Excel to test class

Tags: excel, testing, automated-tests, testng

I have a multiple test cases in single class. Test Excel has three different worksheets/tabs 1, 2 and 3. There are three test cases in my test class.

I looked into data provider annotation; what I understood is it will execute same test case for whole object passed. In my case it will test test case 1 first for all rows from tab 1, test case 2 for all rows from tab 2 and so on.

What I am looking for is as below:

```
    for i number of rows in excel 
     Execute test 1 with row i from tab 1
     Execute test 2 with row i from tab 2
     Execute test 3 with row i from tab 3
     (Form i complete, proceed to second form data)
```

What I could do is read the whole Excel put it in object[][]. Create data providers for each test case and let them run in for loop. For example:

```
    CLASS
    {
     for loop 
      {
          data provider 1, 2, 3;
          @Test
          function testcase1()
          @Test
          function testcase2()
          @Test
          function testcase3()
       }
     }
```

Is it valid approach or does it defeat the purpose of TestNG?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is called [Data-driven testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_testing). Your particular case is a type of the DB part

> - Data pools
> - ODBC sources
> - CSV files
> - Excel files
> - DAO objects
> - ADO objects

IMHO the TestNG feature - parametric testing, is using the same approach. It allow you to run the same test over and over again using different values.

I'm not a big fan of the static test data (see [Pesticide paradox](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=19796&seqNum=6)), my advice is you either generate your Excel files per run (as a [Fresh Fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fresh%20Fixture.html)) or you pass a dynamically generated test data to your tests.

Answer (score 0):

DataProvider takes Method as argument as well.

You can return objects based on the testmethod call.

```
i.e. if testmethod.name = testcase1 - read tab 1 - create object and return
...and so on
```